# How can Set the Random Target From the Player Position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am newbie to Unity. In my project i have instantiates a ball in the player position. From the Player Position the ball should go to random position 40 to 90 degrees. if the player is in 0,0,0 position. the target should be 10,0,0.

I have done the code. But  it is not perfect. I have done something wrong. 
randomly it should set the target.

```
public class Movetowards3: MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    GameObject go;
    public GameObject prefab;
    public GameObject Target;
    public GameObject endPos1;
    public Vector3 endpos2;
    float speed = 5f;
    public bool s=false;
    public GameObject player;
    public bool  s2=false;

    void Start () {
        go = Instantiate(prefab, player.transform.localPosition, Quaternion.identity);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        player=GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");

        if(s==true)
        {

            go = Instantiate(prefab, player.transform.localPosition, Quaternion.identity);
            endpos2 =new Vector3(player.transform.position.x+10f,player.transform.position.y,player.transform.position.z);
            s=false;
        }

        if(go.transform.position != endpos2)
        {
            Vector3 newPos = Vector3.MoveTowards(go.transform.localPosition, endpos2,speed * Time.deltaTime);
            go.transform.position = newPos;
        }
    }
}
```

I have incremented the value of x, but i think it is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

At its core your code is correct, however the issue is that endpos does not have the chance to instantiate.

I think this is your issue:

Here:

```
public bool s=false;
```

You set s to false and you never change it later. This becomes a problem here:

```
if(s==true)
    {

        go = Instantiate(prefab, player.transform.localPosition, Quaternion.identity);
        endpos2 =new Vector3(player.transform.position.x+10f,player.transform.position.y,player.transform.position.z);
        s=false;
    }
```

And, you need these to instantiate to start what you do in the next if statement:

```
   if(go.transform.position != endpos2)
{
    Vector3 newPos = Vector3.MoveTowards(go.transform.localPosition, endpos2,speed * Time.deltaTime);
    go.transform.position = newPos;
}
```

So I would recommend that you either make `public bool s=true;`

Or add and else statement to the first if statement.

Also just a side comment, you instantiate go twice, I don't know if thats intentional but they are doing the same thing.